# Removing Comment Section and Date in Wordpress Projects and Posts

Tags: wordpress

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to hide the comment box and date in WP posts and projects.  I've followed everything and have unchecked the options under the screen options tab for both projects and posts and they are still showing.  Anything other than good old CSS to hide this stuff?

Thanks!

Gerard

Answer (score 0):

You can erase the `HTML` source code directly in yours templates files.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your theme files, and look for your single.php file.

Look for a post meta section, and simply comment out/delete the part that generates the date, more than likely
`<?php the_date(); ?>`

Towards the bottom of the single.php file, there will most likely be some code that adds the comments form, again simply delete or comment it out, maybe: `<?php comment_form(); ?>`

Comment: Thank you! I went in and commented out the php.